# Whenever i open my terminal in vs code my virtual environment automatically starts to run

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How can I disable automatically activating the virtual environment?

Its shows my virtual environment

And i have to again install modules on the environment.

Pls help

Comment: why do you need to install the modules again, if you don't delete the virtual environment the installs remain in the `Lib` directory

Comment: have you checked vscode [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Answer (score 0):

You need to [configure your python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Answer (score 0):

Please click on the Python environment in the lower left corner of VSCode, and select the Pyhon environment you need, then use the shortcut key Cttrl+Shift+` to open a new VSCode terminal, it will automatically enter your currently selected Python environment:

[image]

If you are not using a terminal with activated virtual environment, it is recommended that you click the delete icon("`Kill Terminal`") to delete this terminal window.